# JSON to XML - SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am trying to convert JSON to XML format for sending via API. I have multiple objects that works but those JSON arrays are not multidimensional arrays, so it works. But when i try this function on a deeper array it wont work.

**Array:**

```
public function create_order_direct($plan_id) {
    return $this->__request(__FUNCTION__, [
        "media_id" => 'FACE',
        "client_id" => 'HELL',
        "agreement_id" => '*****',
        "client_reference" => ****,
        "client_contact" => "******",
        "plan_number" => ******,
        "plan_name" => "TEST",
        "cuid" => ******,
        "status" => 'P',
        "colour" => 0,
        "insertion" => [
            "insertion_date" => '2018-09-19',
            "end_date" => '2018-09-20',
            "client_reference" => 1234,
            "price_row" => [
                "price_code" => 000,
                "number_of_units" => 250000,
                "gross" => 1000,
                "discount" => [

                ]
            ],
        ],
        "comment" => "THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER",

    ]);
}
```

**Code:**

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<marathon/>');
//For each element in the array add it as a child node to the xml object.
foreach ($request as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) { //nested array
        $xml->addChild($k);
    } else {
        $xml->addChild($k, $v);
    }
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($xml);
die;

$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
$dom->formatOutput = true;
return $dom->saveXML();
```

**Output:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [media_id] => FACE
    [client_id] => HELL
    [agreement_id] => REDP
    [client_reference] => 123456
    [client_contact] => Asim Tariq
    [plan_number] => 408
    [plan_name] => TEST
    [cuid] => 123456
    [status] => P
    [colour] => 0
    [insertion] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [comment] => THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER
    [type] => create_order_direct
    [password] => *********
    [company_id] => REDP
)
```

**What i need (expected output):**

```
<marathon>
   <media_id>***</media_id>
   <agreement_id>***</agreement_id>
   <client_reference>***</client_reference>
   <client_contact>***</client_contact>
   <plan_number>***</plan_number>
   <plan_name>***</plan_name>
   <cuid>***</cuid>
   <status>***</status>
   <colour>***</colour>
   <insertion>
      <insertion_date>2016-11-20</insertion_date>
      <end_date>201-11-21</end_date>
      <client_reference>123</client_reference>
      <price_row>
         <price_code>000</price_code>
         <number_of_units>2500000</number_of_units>
         <gross>1000</gross>
         <discount>
            <discount_1>100</discount_1>
         </discount>
         <comment>This is a comment!</comment>
      </price_row>
   </insertion>
</marathon>
```

There is a problem in `insertion` section, does not look like it gets iterated.

**Update:`(using: echo $xml->asXML();)`** (i see there is missing from "insertion"--> "price_row" --> "discount"):
FACEREDP123456Asim Tariq408TEST123456P0THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURERcreate_order_direct*********REDP

Comment: What's the actual XML output that your code is generating? Don't use `print_r` to debug SimpleXML objects - it doesn't display everything.

Comment: @hassan: public function addChild ($name, $value = null, $namespace = null) {}

Comment: @iainn. var_dump() gives the same value

Comment: Don't use `var_dump` (or `var_export`, etc) either. SimpleXML objects don't behave like other objects, and trying to use built-in debugging functions to view them won't always work. Run `echo $xml->asXML()` instead, and it'll show you what's actually been built.

Comment: @iainn. It outputs everything without the array that has dept. Ill post it in Question

Comment: Did you find out the problem @iainn ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not add them. You only add the first level of the nested array. To get the deeper levels, you need to refactor the logic into an function. That allows for recursive calls. It it a little easier with DOM:

```
$data = [
    "media_id" => 'FACE',
    "colour" => 0,
    "insertion" => [
        "client_reference" => 1234,
        "price_row" => [
            "price_code" => '000',
            "discount" => [

            ]
        ],
    ],
    "comment" => "THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER"
];

function appendDataToNode(\DOMElement $parent, $data) {
    $document = $parent->ownerDocument;
    if (\is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
            // append an element node for the array element
            $node = $parent->appendChild($document->createElement($name));
            // call itself to append data to the new element node
            appendDataToNode($node, $value);
        }
    } else {
        // append value as a text node
        $node = $parent->appendChild($document->createTextNode($data));
    }
}

$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// create + append a document element
$document->appendChild($document->createElement('marathon'));
// append data to document element
appendDataToNode($documnet->documentElement, $data);

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<marathon> 
  <media_id>FACE</media_id> 
  <colour>0</colour> 
  <insertion> 
    <client_reference>1234</client_reference> 
    <price_row> 
      <price_code>000</price_code> 
      <discount/> 
    </price_row> 
  </insertion> 
  <comment>THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER</comment>
</marathon>
```

Comment: Trying to run this but:         appendDataToNode() must be an instance of DOMElement, array given.
Is it possible to make this work with my already created function?

Comment: Check my example code again, you will have to create a document and the document element before calling `appendDataToNode()` with the document element as the first argument and the data array as the second.

Comment: Now stuck at: createXML() must be an instance of DOMElement, array given

Comment: This function does not exists in the code of your question or in my answer.